# Extract the numeric data from two txt files and write them to a dat file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files namely timedata.txt and veldata.txt. Following is the sample data in timedata file.

```
Time = 0
Time = 0.000112
Time = 0.000224
Time = 0.000336
Time = 0.000448
Time = 0.00056
Time = 0.000672
Time = 0.000784
Time = 0.000896
Time = 0.001008
Time = 0.00112
```

And Following is the sample data in veldata.txt

```
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 0
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.54999
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.67539
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.81389
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.83651
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.85014
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.87054
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.87814
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.87423
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.87499
Average of volScalarField over patch OUTFLOW[0] = 7.8768
```

I need to numeric data  from both these files and merge it to a dat file, with one column as time data and other column as velocity data.So that I can plot those values using gnuplot.

Desired solution would look like this:

```
0         0
0.000112  7.54999
0.000224  7.67539
0.000336  7.81389
0.000448  7.83651
```

and so on ....

I want to write a script using bash so that I can automate the process. Am new to using linux and bash scripting hence I dont know much options.

Any help will be welcomed. Thank you

Comment: Please add your desired output to your question.

Comment: sure .. thank you for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
paste <(awk '{print $NF}' file1) <(awk '{print $NF}' file2)
```

if needed for more then two files perhaps this

```
$ p() { awk '{print $NF}' $1;}; paste <(p file1) <(p file2)
```

this generated tab separated columns, you can make it nicer with piping to `column` as in

```
$ p() { awk '{print $NF}' $1;}; paste <(p file1) <(p file2) | column -t
```

will result

```
0         0
0.000112  7.54999
0.000224  7.67539
0.000336  7.81389
0.000448  7.83651
0.00056   7.85014
0.000672  7.87054
0.000784  7.87814
0.000896  7.87423
0.001008  7.87499
0.00112   7.8768
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but there is no equal spacing between both the column data. Can we correct that ?

Comment: works perfectly and also simple !! I have a question. Is awk used only to get data from file only or it works with data in terminal also

Comment: It can get data from stdin as well

Comment: what does p( ) do I did not understand it

Comment: It's a function definition for common code (DRY principle:  If there are more then 2 files you don't want to repeat the same multiple times.)  For two instances it's a choice of style.

Comment: great Thank you once again

Answer (score 3):

A single `awk` command to get this output:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$NF; next} {print a[FNR], $NF}' timedata.txt veldata.txt
```

To get tabular formatted output use `printf`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$NF; next} {printf "%-12s\t%s\n", a[FNR], $NF}' time.txt veldata.txt

0         0
0.000112  7.54999
0.000224  7.67539
0.000336  7.81389
0.000448  7.83651
0.00056   7.85014
0.000672  7.87054
0.000784  7.87814
0.000896  7.87423
0.001008  7.87499
0.00112   7.8768
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. It works perfectly. I have a question. Is awk used only to get data from file only or it works with data in terminal also.

Comment: awk is suited to handle data that is broken into row-column setup. This data can come directly from files or from output of other commands. So you can also use `command1 | command2 | awk '{...}'`

Comment: Both the answers worked well but I find the other one more simple and easy to understand. Hence I accepted the other one

Comment: Simple may be but just keep in mind that involves invoking of 3 processes, 2 `awk` and 1 `column`. For smaller files it might be okay but for bigger files you will notice performance difference.